# ternary object is not working in react cant pass props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
```

function App() {

```
const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
```

function App() {

```
const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

return (
    <Fragment>
        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/login"
                        element={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Login {...props}/> :<Link to="/home" />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/register"
                        element={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Register {...props} /> : <Link to="/login" />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/home"
                        element={props => !isAuthenticated ? <Home {...props} />: <Link to="/login" />}
                    />
                
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Fragment>
);
```

}

export default App;

Comment: `props => !isAuthenticated ? <Login {...props}/> :<Link to="/home" />` is a **function**. Did you mean for `element` to receive a function? Or did you mean `!isAuthenticated ? <Login {...props}/> :<Link to="/home" />` with no `props =>` at the beginning? (Side note: Typically it's harder to read inversions like that, so perhaps `isAuthenticated ? <Link to="/home" /> : <Login {...props}/>`)

Comment: i was watching a video and i changed render to element to print what is in those components.

Comment: render was not working and props in not printing anything to the page and when i remove it, i get something but the if statement is not working

Comment: Are you developing a web application or a mobile application using react-native?

Comment: web application

Answer (score 0):

```
function App(props){
    //props accessible now to the functional component
    return(
        //your code...
        {
            !(isAuthenticated)?
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/login"
                    element={<Login {...props}/>}
                />
                //other unauthenticated routes
            </Routes>
            :
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/login"
                    element={<Link to="/home" />}
                />
                //other authenticated routes
            </Routes>
        }
    )
}
```

- props would be accessible to routes if they exist on App component.
- you can have 2 sets of authenticated and unauthenticated routes to set based on the authentication state.